# Hide ActionBar icon

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to hide the icons when my drawer nagvigation is shown. The this is that only hide the settings, and not the icon that I want to.

On my MainActivity I've seen that If I add this code the icon hides, but then If I press other fragment to show it crashes.

```
    @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    menu.findItem(R.id.ofertasRefresh).setVisible(!drawerOpen); <--- I want to hide this icon
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

When I press other fragment to show it says ... :

```
01-09 20:03:01.493  25761-25761/info.androidhive.slidingmenu E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 25761
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity.onPrepareOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:170)
        at android.app.Activity.onPreparePanel(Activity.java:2564)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:464)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:800)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:221)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there any way to do it easyly?
By the way, on my fragment 1 I've added an `onCreateOptionsMenu` to show the image and it does perfectly.

```
 @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.refresh_menu, menu);
}
```

R.menu.refresh_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/ofertasRefresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:title="Refresh"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="r"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Cheers.

Comment: When I click on `MainActivity.java:170` the null point is `menu.findItem(R.id.ofertasRefresh).setVisible(!drawerOpen);` I guess this is the null...

Comment: Are you using ActionBarDrawerToggle?

Comment: Can you include your `R.menu.refresh_menu` XML?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way in my opinion is overriding `onDrawerClosed()` / `onDrawerOpened()` methods in your `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. See here:

```
public boolean mDrawerOpened;

    ActionBarDrawerToggle abdt = new ActionBarDrawerToggle( ... ) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View v) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(v);
            mDrawerOpened = false;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            syncState();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View v) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(v);
            mDrawerOpened = true;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            syncState();
        }
```

`invalidateOptionsMenu()` starts a call to the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method in the host Activity. Then:

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (mDrawerOpened) { menu.removeItem(R.id.ofertasRefresh); }
    if (!mDrawerOpened) { menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.ofertasRefresh, Menu.NONE, R.string.title); }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Using visibility (probably works better):

```
public MenuItem mi;

public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (mi == null) { mi = menu.findItem(R.id.ofertasRefresh); }
    if (mDrawerOpened) { mi.setVisible(false); }
    if (!mDrawerOpened) { mi.setVisible(true); }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Or just use visibility if you wish.

Comment: Let me see if I've got this right... The `public boolean...` where I must put it? On my MainActivity.java or on the .java of my fragment? The thing that I get is that this image only shows on a fragment, but the problem is that when I open de drawer it shows.. and i want to put it without visibility...

Comment: The first code needs to be where you are declaring your `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. The second part needs to be in `MainActivity.java`. The fragment does not really matter: we want the icon to be hidden when the drawer is opened, and shown when the drawer is closed (if I got it right).

Comment: The second if on the last code the `(!mDrawerClosed)` do you mean `!mDrawerOpened`, right? The second thing is that the menu.add says "Expected resources of type string"

Comment: Edited my answer. R.string.title is the title of your menuItem. If you don't like managing it this way, try using visibility.

Comment: Thank you so much @m iav ! It worked like a charm. I appreciate your effort. Thanks again! :D

Comment: Tried to do using visibility and when I put `if (mDrawerOpened != null) { mi.setVisible(!mDrawerOpened); }` says : Operator"!=" can not be applied to "bolean", "null"

Comment: My fault. Just remove the condition.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best if you had a menu XML for each fragment and activity. This means you won't have to hide/show certain items. Also regarding callbacks([from the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#ActionBar)):

> The fragment also receives callbacks to onOptionsItemSelected() when a
>   menu item is selected.
>
> Note: Although your fragment receives an on-item-selected callback for
>   each menu item it adds, the activity is first to receive the
>   respective callback when the user selects a menu item. If the
>   activity's implementation of the on-item-selected callback does not
>   handle the selected item, then the event is passed to the fragment's
>   callback. This is true for the Options Menu and context menus.

Comment: If I didn't understand wrong your answer... I think this step I got it, but the problem is that when I open my drawer it still the image visible